# Why are solutions of derivative of function equal to 0 different to solutions of derivative of logarithm of function equal to 0?

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

Consider $f(x)=e^{-x}x^n$, where $n$ is a constant.

Let's search for solutions that cancel out the derivative with respect to x.
We get $x=0$ and $x=n$.

Now, let's consider $g(x)=\ln{f(x)}=-x+n\ln{x}$.
The only solution that cancels out the derivative is $x=n$. Why has the solution $x=0$ disappeared ?

For a positive function that is derivable and without discussing on a extremely complex case, are the solutions that cancel out the derivative of a function the same as the ones that cancel out the derivative of the logarithm of the function ?

Comment: At $x=0$ the logarithm of the function is not defined. You have $$\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = - \infty$$ which corresponds to a "point of infimum" (not a minimum)

Comment: @Crostul : all right thanks. So, if what I wish is to find the solutions of $f(x)$, do you confirm that I *do not have the right* to use the trick of using the logarithm in order to find the solutions, in order to go faster ?

Comment: That gives you the positive solutions.  Consider $x=0$ and $x\lt0$ separately.

Comment: @Empy2 thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick only works if $f(x)$ is positive aat $\alpha$ where $f’(\alpha)=0$ this because by the chain rule you have the derivative of $\ln(f(x)) $ at $\alpha$  is $(1/f(\alpha))*f’(\alpha)$ which is $0$ ,  if $f(\alpha)$ is negative or $0$ then you can’t take log because it is undefined .